# How to push data in a model whose one column is a forign key Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to assign data against specific user using DRF but getting some strange errors. I searched this problem a lot but not able to find any solution.

model.py

```
class Category(TrackingModels):
    name =models.CharField(default='Learning',max_length=150,unique=True,null=False)
    person=models.ForeignKey(to=User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
         return self.name
```

serializer.py

```
class CategorySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    person = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model=Category
        fields=('id','name','person')
```

views.py

```
class CategoryAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class=CategorySerializer
    permission_classes=(IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self,request):
        data={
            "person":request.user.id,
            "name":request.data.get('category')
        }
        serializer=CategorySerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({"message":"Category is created sucessfully!"},status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Here is Postman request:
[image]

[image]

I will really appreciate your answers.
regards,

I followed this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39155423/django-rest-framework-assign-post-data-to-specific-user) but that didn't fixed. I searched a lot on medium and other platforms but all in vein.

Comment: Have you solve this? It because your: ``person = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)` is `read_only`. Just remove `read_only`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below serializer:

```
#import 
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model 
from rest_framework import serializers

UserModel = get_user_model()
class CategorySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    person = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=UserModel.objects.all(), slug_field="id")
    class Meta:
       model=Category
       fields=('id','name','person')
```

Comment: Great. May mark it as accepted.